# Bought a selection of songs off iTunes, they are "greyed out" won't play, can't sync them

Tags: ios

Hey so I bought a heap of songs off iTunes tonight. First 20 I bought off my phone through iTunes, no worries with them. I then got another 8 but these I bought through iTunes on my pc. These 8 won't do anything. They are grey with circles to the left of the check mark. Tried transferring all purchases, downloading all available downloads, Iv checked my account settings there is nothing that says these items are hidden, logged on and off again to iCloud still nothing. Am in-visioning a laptop sized hole in my window :/ any help? :)

Comment: When you say these 8 won't do anything, do you mean they won't download in iTunes on the PC, or you can't do anything with them in the Music app on iOS?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a long shot, but were the ones that are greyed out in .MP3 format by any chance - notice the capitals?   If so, and you rename them to .mp3 in lower case via "Get Info" in Finder, you may, possibly, notice a change.
Good luck.

Comment: The iTunes store does not deliver purchases in MP3 format.